# Connect Bluetooth Mouse automatically

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

My Raspberry Pi works well and I can connect my bluetooth mouse without any problems BUT when the Pi is restarted the mouse has to be reconneted. The mouse is there under bluetooth but needs to reconnect. Here is the crunch, I need a mouse to do this so have to connect a wired mouse to reconnect the blue tooth device. How do I get the Pi to automatically connect the bluetooth mouse each time it is restarted.
Regards and thank you

Thank you for the response and just to let you know that nothing worked. I still have the same challenge. As a test I took the sd card out of the Pi and tried it in another Pi but this was a Pi4. Booted correctly and the bluetooth mouse boots every time the Pi4 is started so I put it down to incompatability with the Pi3.

Thanks to all

Comment: Once paired it should connect, unless paired to another device.

Comment: you must also trust the device ,use 'trust 00:11:22:33:44:55' .

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain how you pair the mouse, because there is more than one user interface for this (presuming the GUI desktop has one, there are also ways to do it from the command line).  If you want help, we need to know that context.  Also note that if you are using the mouse multiple places it may be the mouse that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The mouse is only paired with the Pi and nothing else, and its the bluetooth mouse purchased from the PiHut. I access bluetooth from the GUI. Top toolbar there is the bluetooth icon and clicking on it allows you to add or delete a device. Once paired it also highlights the paired device but offers the oppertunity to connect or disconnect if connected. This pi has been set up for my 10 year old granddaughter to learn scratch and python so it all needs to work on start up. I shall look into the trusting the device. Thats new to me.

Comment: You should edit additional detail into your question, not Comments. I routinely use Bluetooth keyboard and mouse, and if setup as you described it should connect automatically. Unfortunately not all Bluetooth devices are created equal. My mouse connects, mostly, but is often slow. Rolling it round seems to help, but there is nothing you can do on the Pi to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for a solution to the same problem. Turns out I had to set the mouse to be trusted in order for the mouse to reconnect on reboot. When using `bluetoothctl`, I simply entered `trust <mac address>`